# When Update to Latest Xcode Getting Error: "could not build objective-c module csqlite"

Tags: swift, sqlite, xcode9

Updated to latest xcode version and swift sdk now getting error could not build objective-c module 'csqlite' i am using Sqlite Library using CocoaPods i.e **pod 'SQLite.swift'**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After searching losts of material online i have found the solution fortunately not answer at stackoverflow. I just replaced three import statements from **import CSQLite to "import SQLite3"** resolved the problem for me.

Adding answer for helping others having same issue. 
Thanks Peace

[image]

Comment: Oh my God! Thanks a ton for saving my whole day.